# What is actually difference between InputStream and Reader in java

Tags: java

As I searched difference between `InputStream` and `Reader`. I got answered that.

**InputStream:** Byte-Base ( read byte by byte )

**Reader:** Character-Base ( read char by char )

I paste `á` character in file that's ASCII (or may be other Charset) is 225 in my OS and byte's `max_value` is 127. and I used `FileInputStream` to just read() then why it returning 225? how it is able to read more than one byte? because `read()` method just read one byte or character at a time.

Or what is the actually difference between `InputStream` and `Reader`?

Answer (score 1):

`á` does indeed have a unicode value of 225 (that's its code point, and is unrelated to its encoding). When you cast that down to a byte, you'll get -31.  But if you take a careful look at the docs for [InputStream.read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--), you'll see:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. **The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255.**

(emphasis added) The `read` method returns an *int*, not a byte, but that int essentially represents an unsigned byte. If you cast that int down to a char, you'll get back to `á`. If you cast that int down to a byte, it'll wrap down to -31.

A bit more detail:

- `á` has a unicode value of 225.
- chars in Java are represented as UTF-16, which for 225 has a binary representation of `00000000 11100001`
- if you cast that down to a byte, it'll drop the high byte, leaving you with `11100001`. This has a value of -31 if treated as a signed byte, but 225 if treated as unsigned.
- `InputStream.read` returns an int so that it can represent the stream's end as -1. But if the int is non-negative, then only its bottom 8 bits are set (decimal values 0-255)
- When you cast that int down to a byte, Java will drop all but the lowest 8 bits -- leaving you again with `11100001`

Comment: can you give me any example that will exactly practically make difference that `InputStream` read byte by byte and `Reader` char by char? As I tried in question.

Comment: you mean  read `00000000 11100001` and because byte can take 8 bits then it store it as `11100001` that is -31 and then again byte to int. `00000000 00000000 00000000 11100001` that is 255 ?

Comment: Mostly. If you take that byte -31 and just cast it to int, you'll actually still get -31 -- the cast employs "sign extension," which basically means that since the byte's high bit (the sign bit) is 1, the extra bits on the left will be 1 (not 0). But you can then just apply a mask (`i &= 0xff`) to clear those bits.

Comment: I'm trying to understand step by step, as I tried to explain in second last comment. mean read char then convert to byte and then to integer. Can you explain in this way?

Comment: If you're using an InputStream, then you never read a char -- you're reading bytes. But, if the char you wrote is `á`, and you wrote that char using UTF-8 (or Latin-1), then it so happens that the char's representation in that encoding is a single byte -- and everything "just works." If you had tried writing something like `'☃'` to your file, you would find that the byte you read is essentially random; the snowman char is 3 bytes in UTF-8, so you're just reading a third of it. I would highly recommend this primer: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Ok now near to close. Suppose I have byte stream. Like in Socket, Networking ( is it contain only byte(binary) ?) can I use `Reader` instead `InputStream` to read fast? because `Reader` read char(16bits at a time) and InputStream read (8bit at a time)

Comment: Depending on the Reader, it's probably still going to read bytes (e.g. if it's an InputStreamReader) -- it's just going to decode them into chars for you (so that the three bytes that represent the snowman char will come back as just a single `char`). But the big thing is: don't use InputStream or Reader depending on performance needs, use one or the other depending on the _semantics_ you need. If you need chars (that is, text), use Reader. If you need byte (that is, binary data) use InputStream.

Comment: At this point, our conversation is getting too long for SO's format/conventions; this is supposed to be a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. If you have further questions about the differences between bytes and chars, I would encourage you to try and look into it a bit (there are lots of resources online, including the link I posted above), and if you still have questions, ask them as new questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

- `InputStream.read()` returns an int. [That is a value between `0` and `255`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)
- `Byte.MAX_VALUE` is `127` but `Byte.MIN_VALUE` is `-128` which is binary `10000000`. But java does not support unsigned primitives so the most significant byte is always the sign bit.

Comment: what do you mean by `unsigned primitives`?  then why `-127` ?

Comment: that java does not support unsigned primitives means that every primitive in java (byte, int, long etc) reservs one bit for defining if it is positive or a negative.

Comment: The reason for the range `127` to `-128` is that the negatives does not have to define a negative zero so it has one extra possible value.

Comment: Sorry again confused. can you give me link that can help me to understand?

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that an `InputStream` will read the contents of the file as is, with no interpretation: the raw bytes.

A `Reader` on the other hand will use a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) to process the byte input and turn it into a sequence of `char`s instead. And the way it will process the byte input will depend on the [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) used.

And this is not a 1 <-> 1 relationship!

Also, forget about "ASCII values"; Java doesn't use ASCII, it uses Unicode, and a `char` is in fact a UTF-16 code unit. It was a full code point when Java began, but then Unicode defined code points outside the BMP and Java had to adapt: code points over U+FFFF are now represented using a surrogate pair, ie two chars.

See [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.fr/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) for a more detailed explanation.